# Как привязать анонимный обработчик к событию Visual Basic

Tags: visual-basic, события, lambda

Доброго времени, столкнулся с проблемой привязки анонимного обработчика событий к элементу WPF.

```
myImage.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, Sub (o, e)
                                                            anotherMethod(5)
                                                            End Sub)
```

Но во время выполнения получаю исключение "Несоответствие типа обработчика"
Что я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Поискал еще в интернете, наткнулся на такого рода привязывание обработчика

```
AddHandler Button1.Click,   
        Sub(sender, e)  
            Button1.content = "hallo"  
        End Sub
```